# TOS 2x23; Nimoy's resemblance to the Evil one a coincidence, or was it "by design"?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tos, object-identification, props

Was the depiction of "the Evil one" in the holy book held by Cloud William in TOS 2x23 the Omega Glory in a real, recognizable book from real Earth history (as are the flag, pledge, and constitution) or is this a prop drawn to resemble <s>future sad Keanu Reeves</s> Leonard Nimoy?

Screen shots [from here](http://tos.trekcore.com/gallery/thumbnails.php?album=74&page=13).

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Memory Alpha identifies [the prop used](http://memory-alpha.wikia.com/wiki/Bible_(Omega_IV)) as being a standard bible, one that appears in other Paramount properties like "When Worlds Collide", with an additional panel added.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to **"These are the Voyages: Season Two"** by Marc Cushman, the art was created for the episode

[image]

(screen capture from the Kindle edition of the book)

Comment: Mixture of disappointment and relief. Thanks!